# Creating own implementation of Boost::Archive

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, archive

I'm currently creating a concept which uses Boost::Serialization and which needs to implement its own Boost::Archive cause the data has to be serialized in a certain way.

There is documentation about implementing custom archives in the documentation:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

But I'm curious if there are any other (reallife) examples anywhere on the net. I couldn't find any. Perhaps someone could point me to a source or article.

Comment: Why would you want to create a new archive? (just asking).

Comment: I need to serialize data in a certain way (its a binary format which needs the data on specific positions etc). I thought by implementing a custom archive I could achieve this custom formatting and ordering of data.

Comment: IMHO, this would be hard to achieve with Boost.Serialization. It is oriented on class structure, not on data format. I mean latter is adapted to conform former.

Comment: One of the goals of Boost.Serialization, according to its docs: Orthogonal specification of class serialization and archive format. So it should be actually easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example `implementing Log Archive`:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/derivation.html

`Portable Binary archive`:
http://www.systomath.biz/include/Boost-1_35/libs/serialization/doc/derivation.html#portable_archives