# Boost XML serialization save collection in seperate binary file

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost, binary

I'm using Boost to serialize an instance of a class into an XML file. That class contains a collection that I would like to be saved into a separate binary (or ASCII) file. Ideally (but not mandatory), I'd like the XML to contain the path to that separate file. Then, in my main script, I call the static `Save` method to serialize the instance, and later the `Load` method to deserialize it.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
class MyClass
{
  public:

     ...

     friend class boost::serialization::access;
     template<class Archive>
     void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
     {
         ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
         ar & <EXT_BINARY_FILE>(c);
     }

    static void Save(const MyClass& inst, const std::string& filename)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(filename);
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(input);
    }

    static void Load(MyClass& inst, const std::string& filename)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(input);
    }

    private:

        int a;
        std::vector<int> b;
};
```

In the files system I'd obtain the following file tree:

- myclass.xml
- c.dat

Do you know any way to implement this `<EXT_BINARY_FILE>` operation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The **correct** way to do this would be to implement your own archive type¹. This could be involved and I have no experience with it.

So, you can probably mimick it with a [serialization wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html) with some limitations:

- I've not made de tag name configurable
- You might want to inject a target directory to contain the generated binary archives. Right now it just assumes the current working directory is going to make sense.
- object tracking **for nested objects** is out the window: because you write the wrapped objects to a new archive every time, it will always be the first time the object is seen by the tracking for that archive.

### A Simple Wrapper

Here's the wrapper:

```
namespace uuids = boost::uuids;

template <typename T>
struct ExtBinaryFile {
    using base = boost::serialization::nvp<T>;
    ExtBinaryFile(T& ref) : ref_(ref) {}
  private:
    T& ref_;
    friend boost::serialization::access;

    template <typename Ar> void save(Ar& ar, unsigned) const {
        auto src = random_name();
        {
            std::ofstream ofs(src, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive boa(ofs);
            boa << ref_;
        }
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(src);
    }

    template <typename Ar> void load(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        std::string src;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(src);
        {
            std::ifstream ifs(src, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive bia(ifs);
            bia >> ref_;
        }
    }

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned version) {
        boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, version);
        //if constexpr(Ar::is_saving::value) {
            //this->save(ar, version);
        //} else {
            //this->load(ar, version);
        //}
    }

    static std::string random_name() {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
        uuids::basic_random_generator<std::mt19937> gen{prng};
        oss << gen() << ".dat";
        return oss.str();
    }
};
```

As you can see

- I paved over the problem of generating filenames by generating random-based UUIDs.
- The only thing that the XML will contain is a `src` element to contain the filename with the data.

### Type Traits

As given the wrapper would not work because it violates assumptions made by the library regarding object identity. Let's tweak some [serialization traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html) to fix that:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename T> struct is_wrapper<ExtBinaryFile<T> > : std::true_type {};
    template <typename T> struct tracking_level<ExtBinaryFile<T> > {
        static const tracking_type value = tracking_type::track_never;
    };
    // const versions for completeness
    template <typename T> struct is_wrapper<const ExtBinaryFile<T> > : is_wrapper<ExtBinaryFile<T> > {};
    template <typename T> struct tracking_level<const ExtBinaryFile<T> > : tracking_level<ExtBinaryFile<T> > {};
} }
```

There. Now we don't accidentally think the identity of the wrapper is important.

### Demo

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
        auto dat = make_ext_binary(b);

        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a)
           & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dat)
           ;
    }

    static void Save(const MyClass& inst, const std::string& filename) {
        std::ofstream ofs(filename);
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(inst);
    }

    static void Load(MyClass& inst, const std::string& filename) {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(inst);
    }

  //private:
    int a = 0;
    std::vector<int> b;
};

int main() {
    {
        MyClass orig;
        orig.a = 99;
        std::generate_n(back_inserter(orig.b), 1024, ::rand);
        MyClass::Save(orig, "here.xml");
    }
    {
        MyClass roundtrip;
        MyClass::Load(roundtrip, "here.xml");

        std::cout << "a: " << roundtrip.a << " b:" << roundtrip.b.size() << " elements\n";
    }
}
```

As you can see I removed the `private:` for a second so we can prove that the deserialized instance roundtripped correctly.

See It **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa6df7a1cd1f5b0e)**

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_serialization
./a.out; ls -ltrah here.xml *.dat
a: 99 b:1024 elements
-rw-r--r-- 1 2001 2000  365 Jun  9 18:03 here.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 2001 2000 4.1K Jun  9 18:03 55a89355-2637-42e4-b285-9846b046485e.dat
```

`here.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="18">
<inst class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <a>99</a>
    <dat class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <src>e783d3b6-0b23-4fad-be2c-97be9b1e0575.dat</src>
    </dat>
</inst>
</boost_serialization>
```

### Full Code

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa6df7a1cd1f5b0e)**

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <boost/uuid/random_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

namespace uuids = boost::uuids;

template <typename T>
struct ExtBinaryFile {
    using base = boost::serialization::nvp<T>;
    ExtBinaryFile(T& ref) : ref_(ref) {}
  private:
    T& ref_;
    friend boost::serialization::access;

    template <typename Ar> void save(Ar& ar, unsigned) const {
        auto src = random_name();
        {
            std::ofstream ofs(src, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive boa(ofs);
            boa << ref_;
        }
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(src);
    }

    template <typename Ar> void load(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        std::string src;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(src);
        {
            std::ifstream ifs(src, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive bia(ifs);
            bia >> ref_;
        }
    }

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned version) {
        boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, version);
        //if constexpr(Ar::is_saving::value) {
            //this->save(ar, version);
        //} else {
            //this->load(ar, version);
        //}
    }

    static std::string random_name() {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
        uuids::basic_random_generator<std::mt19937> gen{prng};
        oss << gen() << ".dat";
        return oss.str();
    }
};

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename T> struct is_wrapper<ExtBinaryFile<T> > : std::true_type {};
    template <typename T> struct tracking_level<ExtBinaryFile<T> > {
        static const tracking_type value = tracking_type::track_never;
    };
    // const versions for completeness
    template <typename T> struct is_wrapper<const ExtBinaryFile<T> > : is_wrapper<ExtBinaryFile<T> > {};
    template <typename T> struct tracking_level<const ExtBinaryFile<T> > : tracking_level<ExtBinaryFile<T> > {};
} }

template <typename T>
static inline ExtBinaryFile<T> const make_ext_binary(T& ref) {
    return {ref};
}

class MyClass {
  public:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
        auto dat = make_ext_binary(b);

        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a)
           & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dat)
           ;
    }

    static void Save(const MyClass& inst, const std::string& filename) {
        std::ofstream ofs(filename);
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(inst);
    }

    static void Load(MyClass& inst, const std::string& filename) {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(inst);
    }

  //private:
    int a = 0;
    std::vector<int> b;
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        MyClass orig;
        orig.a = 99;
        std::generate_n(back_inserter(orig.b), 1024, ::rand);
        MyClass::Save(orig, "here.xml");
    }
    {
        MyClass roundtrip;
        MyClass::Load(roundtrip, "here.xml");

        std::cout << "a: " << roundtrip.a << " b:" << roundtrip.b.size() << " elements\n";
    }
}
```

---

¹ [Creating own implementation of Boost::Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921151/creating-own-implementation-of-boostarchive)